# Start process and Stop process buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net

I spent many days in this problem but have not found a solution.
I have a button that the user uses to starts a process that can take several minutes. This process does some calculations and at the end I have to see the end result in a textbox.
There must be another button to stop the process. If the user stops the process before the process is finished, I have to see the partial result in the textbox. 
How can I do?
I tried to use a timer and an updatepanel but I could not find a solution.

```
protected void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (j=0;j<1000;j++)  //it lasts some minutes...
    {
       textbox1.text = j   //it's only an example to understand what I need...
       if (stopped==true) return;
    }

}

protected void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     stopped=true;
}
```

Comment: You should ditch the update panel. It's only going to complicate your solution. You're wanting [background jobs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) to run on the server, you need to handle them properly.

Comment: @mason do you suggest me to use one of the solutions contained in that link even if, in any case, in my web application the user have to wait for the end of the process?

Comment: Yes. Start a background task then poll the server to see if it's done or have it notify the user via SignalR.